# SQL UPDATE all values in a field with appended string CONCAT not working

Tags: sql, mysql, concatenation

Here is what I want to do:

current table:

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | max         |  
|  2 | linda       |  
|  3 | sam         |  
|  4 | henry       |  
+----+-------------+
```

Mystery Query ( something like `"UPDATE table SET data = CONCAT(data, 'a')"` )

resulting table:

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | maxa        |  
|  2 | lindaa      |  
|  3 | sama        |  
|  4 | henrya      |  
+----+-------------+
```

thats it! I just need to do it in a single query, but can't seem to find a way. I am using mySQL on bluehost (I think its version 4.1)

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you actually tried your query? It should "just work"

Comment: Yes I have tried it. I thought it should just work too.

Comment: here is my 'real life' return: [SQL] UPDATE questions_national
SET cat_id = CONCAT(cat_id,'a')

Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.069ms

Comment: Is `cat_id` a character field (varchar, text, etc) or numeric?

Comment: was not working for me (SQL 2012)so I tried "update t set data=data+'a'" works fine..

Answer (score 329, accepted):

That's pretty much all you need:

```
mysql> select * from t;
+------+-------+
| id   | data  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | max   |
|    2 | linda |
|    3 | sam   |
|    4 | henry |
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> update t set data=concat(data, 'a');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t;
+------+--------+
| id   | data   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | maxa   |
|    2 | lindaa |
|    3 | sama   |
|    4 | henrya |
+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Not sure why you'd be having trouble, though I am testing this on 5.1.41

Comment: The `concat` function in 4.1 looks the same - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Solved it. Turns out the column had a limited set of characters it would accept, changed it, and now the query works fine.

Comment: I have somewhat the same senario, except i want to replace all the double quotes with single quotes. Any suggestions how can i do that?

Comment: This was a good answer, but a little confusing, since on my server 'data' was a keyword. Maybe a less ambiguous example would be:
`UPDATE table SET column_name=concat(column_name, 'string');`

Answer (score 47):

CONCAT with a null value returns null, so the easiest solution is:

> UPDATE myTable SET spares = IFNULL (CONCAT( spares , "string" ), "string")

Comment: Perfect solution.

Answer (score 19):

convert the `NULL` values with empty string by wrapping it in `COALESCE`

```
"UPDATE table SET data = CONCAT(COALESCE(`data`,''), 'a')"
```

OR

Use [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead:

```
"UPDATE table SET data = CONCAT_WS(',',data, 'a')"
```

Answer (score 17):

```
UPDATE 
    myTable
SET 
    col = CONCAT( col , "string" )
```

Could not work it out. The request syntax was correct, but "0 line affected" when executed.

The solution was :

```
UPDATE 
    myTable 
SET 
    col = CONCAT( myTable.col , "string" )
```

That one worked.

Answer (score 13):

```
UPDATE mytable SET spares = CONCAT(spares, ',', '818') WHERE id = 1
```

not working for me.

spares is `NULL` by default but its `varchar`

Comment: it seems, that if the value is NULL by default it doesnt work. it has to be an empty string

Comment: `UPDATE mytable SET spares = CONCAT(COALESCE(spares, ''), ',', '818') WHERE id = 1`  This will work. It uses a blank string `''` when it runs into null values.

Answer (score 9):

Solved it. Turns out the column had a limited set of characters it would accept, changed it, and now the query works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
Update myTable
SET spares = (SELECT CASE WHEN spares IS NULL THEN '' ELSE spares END AS spares WHERE id = 1) + 'some text'
WHERE id = 1
```

field = field + value  does not work when field is null.

Comment: Can you really use + with strings in mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = CONCAT('text', column_name)
```