# MySQL query to insert an x before every value in column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table and want to add 'x' to the beginning of a column value for every row.

My syntax guess was:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col5='x'.col5
```

This did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table1 set col5 = 'x' + col5
```

Comment: Is it faster than using CONCAT?

Comment: I didn't try it but I guess it will be optimized to the same

Answer (score 4):

```
update table1 
set col5 = CONCAT('x', col5)
where col5 NOT LIKE 'x%'; -- optional, depending on circumstances
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table1 SET col5 = CONCAT('x', col5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [MySQL CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE table1 SET col5 = CONCAT('x',col5)
```

- [SQL UPDATE all values in a field with appended string CONCAT not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128335/sql-update-all-values-in-a-field-with-appended-string-concat-not-working)