# How to update a column from database , but just to add something to the current value

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Let say I have something like this:

```
id |    title   |

1  |  First row |
```

Now I want to update that value to be: *First row is here*, by just adding *is here*. And as you think, there is more than one row, and I want to update all the rows dynamically.

```
UPDATE posts SET title=title+' is here'
```

I know that the above is wrong, I just thought that since it works with numbers, maybe it will also with text, but it doesn't.

Comment: Numeric: id = id + 1. String: use one/some of the string functions MySQL has, e.g. concat or similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL UPDATE all values in a field with appended string CONCAT not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128335/sql-update-all-values-in-a-field-with-appended-string-concat-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `concat`:

```
UPDATE posts SET title=concat(title,'your_string_to_add') WHERE id='your_id'
```

It is important to give `WHERE id = 'id'` otherwise it will update the first row I beleive. In your case:

```
UPDATE posts SET title=concat(title,' is here') WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 6):

To do that you need to concatenate strings, MySQL has the function [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), so your query would be:

```
UPDATE posts SET title=CONCAT(title,' is here')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE posts SET title=CONCAT(title,' is here')
```