# MySQL, adding a string to all column values

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Have a MySQL database table with 2 columns:
id, url

The url column has values like 'http://www.example.com/'.

I need to add a string like 'http://www.x.com?redirect=' to the beginning of all the column values - i.e. to change the values like this:
http://www.example.com/ ===> http://www.x.com?redirect=http://www.example.com/

Anyone has some clues to how I can do that?

I have looked into using CONCAT(), but so far I haven't been able to make it work :(

Thanks a lot for your help,
Louisa

Comment: Do you want to add said prefix permanently (i.e. update the table's content), or only add it in the results of a `SELECT` query?  Moreover, does this sort of processing not more appropriately belong in the presentation layer of your application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using concat it would be like this:

```
update table set url=concat('http://www.x.com?redirect=',url);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Plain and simple solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you use can use `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('http://www.x.com?redirect=', url) AS url
FROM yourtable
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c074e/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Update myTable
SET data= (SELECT CASE WHEN data IS NULL THEN '' ELSE data END AS data WHERE id = 1) + 'some text'
WHERE id = 1
```

field = field + value  does not work when field is null.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at code snippet from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128384):

> `update t set data=concat(data, 'a');`

Something similar should work:

> `update t set data=concat('http://www.x.com?redirect=', data);`