# Store Text with Line Break in MySQL DataBase

Tags: php, mysql

So i have a Simple Question , i am trying to get the Text from an Html Form , then add a '\n' on each Request , for Line Break , i have tried this :

```
 '".$customtext."'.'\n'
```

Or this :

```
 '".$customtext.'\n'"'
```

with no luck , is there a way to do it ?

Thanks you .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes (For example: $var_to_print = $str . "\n";) // will not work using simple quote '

I'm not sure if u are looking for this, or may you want to use a while/foreach bucle to replace each "\n" to "< br>"

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks you , as Matthias Said , its work , but i am looking to Append the Text to the DataBase

Answer (score 0):

Try `$customtext."\n"` -- double quotes should fix the problem.
Edit: and if you want to output within HTML code you can take a look at the function `nl2br`.

Comment: does not work :/ , no i dont want within HTML , i want to store as it is in the DataBase

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you give us some code + output data?

Comment: $sq6="UPDATE $name SET customtext='".$customtext."'."\n" WHERE idname='".$customtext1."'"; this Code provide me a Script Error

Comment: `$sq6="UPDATE $name SET customtext='".$customtext."\n"' WHERE idname='".$customtext1."'";` -- I guess you want the newline within the customertext?

Comment: Yes . i am Sorry about the Title , my Real Question is : How to Append some Text to the MySQL DataBase with a Line Break

Comment: Then take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128335/sql-update-all-values-in-a-field-with-appended-string-concat-not-working -- or directly look for "concat" in mySQL. Otherwise you could first have a SELECT and then an UPDATE query.